# Selecting Range Dynamically till the last cell in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, range

I have a VBA code with the following.

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:J2002")
```

This can select till the last entry in column J when it has exactly 2002 entries. What I want is a general one which can select between H2 and the last entry in J column. I found the following

```
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

But I am not understanding, how I can use the value of Lastrow to select the last cell in column J.

Comment: range("H2:J" & Lastrow)

Comment: Thank You Sivaprasath V. It worked.

Comment: if you want to get the `LastRow` in Column "J", you need to use `Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row`. However, you should try to stay away from `ActiveSheet`, and use fully qualified objects instead, like `Lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row
'lastrow now holds last occupied cell in column 10 ie J
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:J" & lastrow)
```